# How can I make shortcut in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, shortcut

I have a button . How do I add a shortcut to my iPhone's home page when it is clicked???

And when the icon is clicked again, the app will open again
Exactly like safari add to home screen

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create shortcut as on `Windows` or `Anroid`.

Comment: I want to create shortcut on ios

Comment: @soroush There is no way.

Comment: Sorry i have another question. do you know how to get page title in webkitview